# Allowing only one user to log in at a time

Tags: linux

I have a special lab machine (linux) and two different users will be using this machine. They need to log in with the same userid. I want to prevent both of them from logging in at the same time. How can I do that?

I was thinking of starting with something simple like this - Use the users source IP-address and add some checks in `.bashrc` :

If a user logs in from IPAddress1 and there is already somebody ssh'ed in from IPAddress2 then print a big fat message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [pam_limits](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits) to do this too. Add a line like

```
fred    hard    maxlogins    1
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf` and it will only allow the user `fred` to log in up to 1 (maxlogins) times.

Comment: that's a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your plan sounds reasonable. Maybe do a check against something like `last [username] | grep "still logged in" | wc -l`  in bashrc ? - could check for the ip there, also.

Comment: perfect. I did not know about last. last -d is what I will use. Thanks.